# EV Certificate in Visual Studio with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, certificate, visual-studio-2015

We recently purchased an EV certificate from digicert which we will be using to sign our clickonce deployed software.
I am able to chose the certificate from the hardware dongle and can use it in VS 2015 (Win 8.1 or Win 10) to sign the clickonce manifest as well as the assembly.

But when installing or updating the software the installer as well as smartscreen on 8.1 / 10 says "Unknown publisher". Right clicking the application exe file and shows the correct certificate and publisher under digital signatures.

I fail to see where the problem might be, or what we have done wrong.

Does anyone know how to correctly sign a clickonce application using an EV certificate, or what we have done wrong? Is there a known bug to VS 2015 with EV certificates?

Comment: Did you assign the Publisher Name in the properties of your project before publishing  ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Yes, the publisher name is set.